# jpa : eager vs lazy loading in child entity

Tags: java, jpa, lazy-loading, eager-loading

I have 2 classes

***Student.java***

```
public class Student {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int student_id;
private String student_name;
@OneToMany(mappedBy ="student", cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.LAZY )
private List<Book> books;

//the getters and setters
}
```

***Book.java***

```
 public class Book
    { @Id
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
      private int book_id;
      private String book_name;
      @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
      private Student student;
    
    //the getters and setters
    }
```

I know that the difference between the eager loading and lazy loading is that eager loading helps you to load all your needed entities at once but lazy loading loads them when needed. So for my Student class, and because I'm using LAZY loading it loads the student_id, the student_name but doesn't load the list books until I call the getBooks() methods . It's clear for the parent entity .
But for the child entity , it's a bit confusing. What is the difference between using eager loading and lazy loading inside the class Book (in a @ManyToOne relationship)

Comment: Your question is not clear. In the Book object it would act the same way, the student object would be lazy loaded.

Comment: so why most people use lazy on parent class and eager on child ?

Comment: You you in parent class as it has a list. This has to load many data from the database. These could in turn have relations with other classes causing it to load every thing which is not needed. Where as in the child class which in your case is a `@ManyToOne` is just a single object. That's why the default fetch type of `@ManyToOne` is eager.